# how to retrieve image from ms-access database in mvc3 using jquery template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, jquery-templates

Save the image in a web directory and store the URL on database.
and should i use actionresult for controller or any other option available?
in output again it is showing url like asd/dad/daaf/img.png?? should i give url from application name? or images/abc.png?

> how to get image using filepathresult based on imageid in controller from database

Comment: Using MS Access for anything that could remotely have multiple users like a web site is a really really bad idea.  At least consider using SQL Express which is designed more for a multi-tenant environment.

Comment: but i had already prepared database. now i need to retrieve images from database

Comment: I have no idea - I haven't used MS Access in this way.  But, like I said, if you are going to have more than a couple of users using the site at the same time, prepare for a lot of concurrency issues using MS Access.  You should really think about migrating your data.

Comment: no no, users can see the site,thats it.